How to enforce Face ID only Apple Pay?
Even if you disable double tap to apple pay and enforce Face ID for the wallet app you can still get the wallet to pop up when approach to pay on a NFC terminal. Then you can ignore face ID and tap "pay with PIN".
Is there a way to enforce face ID for apple pay in a way that cannot be overridden by PIN?
Context: thieves on Brazil make you tell the PIN when robbing you

No, there is no way to enforce Face ID (or Touch ID) for Apple Pay in a way that cannot be overridden by your passcode. Your passcode acts as a "backup" when conditions for Face ID or Touch ID are not met.
Note that card issuers can choose to enable their cards for Face ID use only; you could suggest your bank to do so or find a bank that offers that service.

Stolen Device Protection prevents doing many things with just a PIN code, but does not apply to payment cards.
You would have to call your bank and de-activate your card in case your device is stolen.

you cannot add another face when theft protection is on and to disable theft proteciton it takes 1 hour and the face again

@GuerlandoOCs thank you for reminding me, I have removed that line
